# What kind of heuristics for BFS use to solve this 'game' (find path)?

Tags: graph-algorithm, path-finding, heuristics

I want to solve a 'game'.
I have 5 circles, we can rotate circles into left or into right (90 degrees).

Example:

[image]

[image]

Goal: 1,2,3,....,14,15,16
Ex. of starting situations: 16,15,14,...,3,2,1

I'm using BFS to find path but I can't invent heuristic function (my every solutions are not good). I was trying manhattan distance and others... (Maybe idea is good but something wrong with my solution). Please help!

Comment: BFS + Heuristics sounds like a kind of `A*`. Try searching for stuff on `A*`

Comment: "BFS" usually means "breadth-first search."  What you're asking for is essentially A*.

Comment: @Bart No, but A* is best-first.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you might try is to do a breadth-first search backward from the goal state.  Stop it early.  Then you can terminate your (forward from the initial state) search once you've hit a state seen by the backward search.

Sum of Manhattan distances from pieces to their goals is a decent baseline heuristic for the forward A* search.  You can do rather better by adding up the number of turns needed to get 1-8 into their places to the number of turns needed to get 9-16 into their places; each of these state spaces is small enough (half a billion states or so) to precompute.

Comment: The truncated backwards BFS is a good idea, but I think Manhattan distance might not apply here at all (or be a bad heuristic): a single rotation can move 4 numbers 1 MH distance unit closer to their destinations, so in general if the total MH distance-from-correct-position (summed over all numbers) is x, to get a lower bound (i.e. admissible heuristic value) on the number of rotations needed you must divide x by 4.

Comment: Seems I imagined the word "admissible" was in the OP's question...  This should be a good overall heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

A simple conservative (admissible) heuristic would be:

1. For each number 1 <= i <= 16, find the minimum number of rotations needed to put i back in its correct position (disregarding all other numbers)
2. Take the maximum over all these minimums.

This amounts to reporting minimum number of rotations needed to position the "worst" number correctly, and will therefore never overestimate the number of moves needed (since fixing all numbers' positions simultaneously requires at least as many moves as fixing any one of them).

It may, however, underestimate the number of moves needed by a long way.  You can get more sophisticated by calculating, for each number 1 <= i <= 16 and for each wheel 1 <= j <= 5, the minimum number of rotations of wheel j needed by any sequence of moves that positions i correctly.  For each wheel j, you can then take a separate maximum over all numbers i, and finally add these 5 maxima together, since they are all independent.  (This may be less than the previous heuristic, but you are always allowed to take the greater of the two, so this won't be a problem.)

Comment: I was create new topic for this subject [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497102/solving-game-implementing-heuristics#23497102) , please answer there

Answer (score 1):

One heuristic that you could use is the cumulative number of turns that it takes to move each individual segment to its designated spot. The individual values would range from zero (the item is in its spot) to five (moving corner to corner). The total for the goal configuration is zero.

One has to be careful using this heuristic, because going from the initial configuration to the desired configuration may require steps when the cumulative number of turns *increases* after a move.

Finding a solution may require an exhaustive search. You need to memoize or use another DP technique to avoid solving the same position multiple times.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "cumulative"?  Also how are you proposing to combine the numbers of turns for each segment?  (I think you can take the maximum, but you can't add them, for example, because some moves that move segment 1 closer to its destination might also move segment 2 closer to its destination.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker By "cumulative" I mean "total"; this metrics does not represent the number of moves - it measures how far you are from the goal in relative terms. This measure is not straight line, either, because you may need to go back to a higher measure.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The individual distances need to be computed in isolation of each other, so there will be some double-counting. This measure should be OK to decide on the order in which you evaluate the newly added combinations.

Comment: Ah, yes this should be a decent heuristic.  I originally thought s/he needed an *admissible* heuristic (i.e. lower bound on number of moves, for A*) but it seems that's not the case.  This might be more accurate, even if it can both under- and overestimate.