# Prolog - Solving game, implementing heuristics

Tags: algorithm, path, prolog

I want to solve a 'game'.
I have 5 circles, we can rotate circles into left or into right (90 degrees).

Example:

[image]

[image]

Goal: 1,2,3,....,14,15,16
Ex. of starting situations: 16,15,14,...,3,2,1

I'm using BFS.

Heuristic function:

```
       heuristic(NextState,Goal,H)),
```

Desctiption of function:

```
For each number 1 <= i <= 16, find the minimum number of rotations needed to put i back in its correct position (disregarding all other numbers)
Take the maximum over all these minimums.
```

This amounts to reporting minimum number of rotations needed to position the "worst" number correctly, and will therefore never overestimate the number of moves needed (since fixing all numbers' positions simultaneously requires at least as many moves as fixing any one of them).

How it should be looks?

Example for circle A:

```
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),0).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,A,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),1).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,A,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),4).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,A],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),5).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),1).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,A,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),2).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,A,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),3).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,A],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),4).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),4).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,A,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),3).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,A,_],[_,_,_,_]),4).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,A],[_,_,_,_]),5).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[A,_,_,_]),5).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,A,_,_]),4).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,A,_]),5).
heuristic(tiles([A,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,A]),6).
```

Is it a good idea?

Comment: Standard BFS does not allow for heuristics. A* can use your heuristic because it is admissible. You might also want to link to the [earlier discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482081/what-kind-of-heuristics-for-bfs-use-to-solve-this-game-find-path) for reference (I believe your heuristic is based on dasblinkenlight's answer and j_random_hacker's comment, probably you should attribute them properly)

Comment: in Best first, diferences from BFS : associate heuristic value with each path H:Path, since extend needs to know heuristic values for pahts, must pass Goal to extend, once new the new paths have been appended, they mus be sorted(in decreseing order by heuristic value) and we must deifne the heuristic function for this problem

Comment: what you describe there is exactly the A* algorithm

Comment: procedural description of best first search

must keep track of all current paths w/ hvals, initially: [ Hval:[Start] ]

look at first path in the list of current paths
if the path ends in a goal, then DONE
otherwise,
remove the first path
generate all paths by extending to each possible move
add the newly extended paths to the list, sorted by (decreasing) hval 
recurse

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement the admissible heuristic I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23482276/47984).

I can't tell what you're trying to do with your "example for circle A" code at all, I'm afraid.  The way to calculate the minimum number of rotations needed to move a particular number i from its current position to its final, correct position is by treating it as a special kind of **shortest-path problem**, in which:

1. There is a vertex for each position that i could be in (so 16 vertices in all).
2. There is an edge between a pair of vertices x and y whenever there is a circle that can be rotated 90 degrees (in either direction) to move whatever number is in position x to position y.

For concreteness, let's label the positions (and therefore the vertices) with letters A-P as follows:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
```

So for example the edges leaving vertex B are to:

1. A (since rotating the top-left wheel anticlockwise will move whatever is at B to A)
2. F (since rotating the top-left wheel clockwise will move whatever is at B to F)

Rotating any of the other 4 wheels has no effect on the number in position B, so those are the only edges leaving vertex B.

Some other vertices have more edges.  E.g. F has edges to:

1. B (rotating the top-left wheel anticlockwise)
2. E (rotating the top-left wheel clockwise)
3. G (rotating the centre wheel clockwise)
4. J (rotating the centre wheel anticlockwise)

Edges are unweighted (or equivalently, have weight 1) and are bidirectional, since every 90-degree rotation can be undone by the reverse rotation.

Suppose we want to calculate the minimum number of rotations needed to get the number 9 from its initial position (let's say B) to its final, correct position, I.

Traversing an edge is equivalent to rotating some circle 90 degrees, so to find the minimum number of rotations needed to move number 9 from position B to position I, we want to find a path connecting vertices B and I that uses the minimum possible number of edges.  Because all edges have weight 1, this can be solved efficiently using breadth first search (if edges had various weights, you could use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) instead).  In the case of 9, the answer will be 3 (e.g. B->F->J->I).

So, that explains how to calculate the minimum number of rotations for moving a particular number home.  To calculate the heuristic, do this for each of the numbers in the initial configuration, and pick the maximum overall.  (Notice that the graph is the same in each case -- only the start and destination vertices will change.)  This is your guaranteed-admissible heuristic rotation count value.

Comment: I think that this is the same as (moving 9 from B to I position)`heuristic(tiles([_,B,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),tiles([_,_,_,_],[_,_,_‌​,_],[B,_,_,_],[_,_,_,_]),3).`

Comment: @Bart: Where do you get the 3 from?

Comment: Every values are 'hand-calculated'

Comment: @Bart: ... so don't you want to know how to calculate those values *automatically*?  That's what I'm telling you how to do!

Comment: Yes it's the best way but i don't know how to implemenet this in Prolog

Comment: @Bart: I didn't realise the question was about Prolog.  I see it's in the tags, but it wasn't in your earlier question, and it's hard to notice unless you draw attention to it!  I have zero idea how to implement this in Prolog I'm afraid, though I imagine it can handle depth-first searches easily, and there's probably a way to calculate the shortest paths using DFS somehow.